# homebrew-php is deprecated. what to use instead?

Tags: php, homebrew

I'm used to installing php72 and php's required extensions using homebrew-php for.. homebrew on MacOS High Sierra :)

now when I go to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php it says that it's deprecated and it was removed or merged with core. i can see that `brew` has php package but no way to install more extensions.

is there a different repository I need to tap now ?

in general... i need the mysql, intl and opcache extensions which do not come by default. what do I do ?

Comment: you can directly install php extensions with brew. What are you trying to install?

Comment: According to docs, it has been merged with Homebrew-core. You should  upgrade brew and install php 
Here is a good snippet https://gist.github.com/shashankmehta/6ff13acd60f449eea6311cba4aae900ahttps://gist.github.com/shashankmehta/6ff13acd60f449eea6311cba4aae900a . 
Then install extension with brew, or without it.

Comment: What I did, I cleared old versions, untapped 3rd party taps and installed just `brew install php` and that gave me PHP 7.2. 

Since I am still actively using PHP5.6, I installed also `brew install php@5.6`, but currently I am having some trouble with Valet, when I want to use it with 5.6 instead of 7.2.

Comment: @Rozkalns - that was the way to go :) homebrew's php package contains most of the extensions I needed.. and I installed the missing ones with pecl. please post as answer so i'll accept it :)

Comment: I think my answer here explains it pretty well. It's not too tough. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529784/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to replace homebrew with macports to install missing extensions. I personally prefer to stick to homebrew if possible.

PHP package for homebrew comes with most required extension.
I used pecl to install any other extension I needed.

thanks and have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into some major roadblocks trying to stay with homebrew for php56 on MacOS High Sierra.  It was forcing me to use Pear/Pecl to install my dependencies like dblib, memcached, mcrypt, etc. When I tried to get memcached setup it only had a version available for php7x.  In disappointment I threw up my hands and removed homebrew from my system and installed macports.  I was able to get all of my subtle dependencies working.  It wasn't a pleasant path, but it's better than nothing.

- Remove homebrew: https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/48792
- Install macports: https://www.macports.org/install.php

I hope this helps.