# Homebrew: install new formula php72-imagick

Tags: homebrew, imagick

I need install imagick module on my php 7.2

I see

```
brew search php72
==> Searching local taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
==> Searching blacklisted, migrated and deleted formulae...
No formula found for "php72".
Closed pull requests:
...
php72-imagick 3.4.3 (new formula) (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/pull/4267)
```

How can I do it?

Also I need support for argon

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It all changed back in April 2018 I think. **Homebrew** no longer acts as the package manager for PHP, so all the `php-imagick` and `php-redis` and `php-other-extension` stuff has gone and you are now supposed to manage PHP packages using `pecl` like everyone else does.

So, how to get Imagick under PHP? Note that **Imagick** and **ImageMagick** are two different things:

- ImageMagick is the entire ImageMagick suite
- Imagick is *just* the PHP binding

Here are the steps - if anyone knows better or any improvements, let me know via comment and I will update.

---

**Step 1 - Delete anything likely to conflict**

Before starting, it is best to clean up all the stuff that is broken or unneeded. Do as many of these as you are comfortable with:

```
brew rm php php@5.6 php@7.0 php@7.1
brew rm imagemagick
```

---

**Step 2 - Update Xcode command line tools and get build packages**

Make sure you have installed Xcode command-line tools with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Go to AppStore and click on **Updates** and update any Xcode related packages - especially if you have recently upgraded macOS.

Install homebrew building tools:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

---

**Step 3 - Install ImageMagick**

Check what ImageMagick options you want with:

```
brew options imagemagick
```

I like to use:

```
brew install imagemagick --with-x11 --with-librsvg --with-openexr --with-pango
hash -r
```

but you may like vanilla install:

```
brew install imagemagick
hash -r
```

---

**Step 4 - Install homebrew PHP**

Next, install the **homebrew** version of PHP with:

```
brew install php
hash -r                    # Update bash's internal paths
```

Now, critically ensure you are running the correct **homebrew** PHP:

```
type php
```

If that tells you:

```
/usr/local/...anything.../php
```

you are running **homebrew** PHP and you can go to the next step.

If it tells you:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

you are running the Apple-supplied PHP. If that is what you want to run, ignore my entire answer which is predicated on you wanting to use **homebrew** PHP. If you get this answer but want to run **homebrew** PHP, your PATH is set incorrectly. You need to put `/usr/local/bin` **before** `/usr/bin` to pick up all **homebrew** packages ahead of Apple programs, i.e.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This step gives you `pecl` - the PHP Package Manager - as well, since it is part of **homebrew** PHP.

---

**Step 5 - Install Imagick**

Now you can install Imagick with `pecl`:

```
pecl install imagick
```

---

If anything goes wrong, here are some related questions and answers...

*Q1. How can I find where my `php.ini` file is?*

Try any of these commands:

```
pecl config-get php_ini                  # I get "/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini"
brew info php
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration"     # I get "Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php.ini"
```

*Q2. How can I find where `pecl` installs modules?*

```
pecl config-get ext_dir                 # I get "/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718"
```

*Q3. How can I tell what PHP modules are loaded?*

```
php -m
```

*Q4. Why can't PHP find my module?*

First locate your modules directory using Q2. I like to put that in the clipboard with:

```
pecl config-get ext_dir | pbcopy
```

Then edit the `php.ini` file from Q1. I use `vi`, so I would do:

```
vi "$(pecl config-get php_ini)"
```

Then find the line in that file that looks like this:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
```

and, then (using the contents of your paste buffer) make the following line look like this (no semi-colon at the start):

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/XXXXXX"
```

on my machine `XXXXXX` is `20170718`. If you get this right, any and all modules you install via `pecl` will be visible to your **homebrew** PHP.

*Q5. How can I see all my PHP settings?*

Check PHP configuration, versions and settings with:

```
php -i
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot! I was having issues due missing imagemagick library.

Comment: 'brew rm php php@5.6 php@7.0 php@7.1' gave me an error message that those casks did not exist, all worked apart from that

Comment: Bless you! But  
1. I had to add the `mkdir /usr/local/lib/php/pecl` dir before `pecl install imagick` and  
2. clean the `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d` dir to get rid of PHP warnings

Comment: @Mark Setchell - I can't thank you enough for this detailed explanation and overview!  I've been struggling to get Imagemagick installed, and you sir have saved me!  Thank you so, so much!

Comment: Thanks for this. God look at all those steps just to get imagick up and running.

Comment: @Mark Setchell `pecl install imagick` -> `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/imagick` on High Sierra

Comment: @Mirko same message happened to me, anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

In my case (PHP 7.2.10 with Homebrew) works:

```
pecl install imagick
```

Open the file **php.ini** and remove extension line with imagick extension.

Check *.ini files with

```
php --ini
```

You can see paths to extension files. Create or edit imagick ini file.

```
subl /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/ext-imagick.ini
```

The content of file may be (check the path to imagick.so)

```
[imagick]
extension="/usr/local/opt/php/pecl/20170718/imagick.so"
```

And restart php with

```
brew services restart php
```

Try, if the error message dissapear:

```
php -v
```

And check imagick extension with:

```
php -i | grep imagick
```

If you see line with **imagick module => enabled** you have solved a problem.

Answer (score -1):

You want `php72-gmagick`, GraphicsMagick is a fork from ImageMagick 5.5.2.

Or, you can `pecl install imagick` still.