# Unable to install memcached via homebrew due to deprecation. PECL doesn't work either

Tags: php, memcached, homebrew

So our friends at Homebrew have gone and changed things.  They've deprecated Homebrew/PHP.  That's fine, that's what we developers do.  I was able to successfully install PHP 5.6 using Homebrew on a fresh installation of OS X High Sierra.  I'm trying now to install memcached and mcrypt, but with the Homebrew change I understand this needs to be done through Pear/PECL.  However when I trying to use PECL, I get the following error message:

```
$ sudo pecl install memcached
pecl/memcached requires PHP (version >= 7.0.0), installed version is 5.6.36
```

I'm wondering now what my options are.  I need to stay with PHP 5.6 for now because that's what I need to code against until I can get our stuff up to PHP 7.x.

Comment: You could use Docker (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/) and do it without homebrew.

Comment: You will need to specifically state the version you need. https://serverfault.com/questions/631479/how-to-install-an-older-version-of-a-pecl-package `pecl install -f memcached-2.2.0` See: https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached for version details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529784/2836621

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with Docker.  I'm learning it now and it is a breath of fresh air.  I'm certain it will work.