# ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to install Imagick on my Mac, but I get this error after I use:

```
sudo pecl install imagick
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/imagick
```

and here is the console log:

```
downloading imagick-3.4.3.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.4.3.tgz (245,410 bytes)
...................................................done: 245,410 bytes
19 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20160303
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
Please provide the prefix of Imagemagick installation [autodetect] :
```

If I press return, then it keeps loading lots of things and then I get the error:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/include/php/ext/imagick/php_imagick_shared.h'
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/imagick
```

Comment: What happens if you switch to the root user (`sudo -i`) and attempt to install?

Comment: Try creating the folder first. Or check if it already exists.

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1071146

Comment: @SamJudge sadly the same result

Comment: Hmm, if it's not a permissions issue, it might be something wrong with the installer. If you've tried Jonathan's suggestion and that also did not work, or produced different errors, an alternative option might be to download the source code and manually compile the shared library files with phpize http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php

Comment: Step 1. `Search for: "ERROR: failed to mkdir"`. Step 2. Find out its a permission issue. Step 3. Fix the permission issue.... I cannot simplify it better.

Comment: I had similar issues and i was able to resolve them by cleaning the older php installations and then doing a fresh install. you may try same. http://www.testerlogic.com/install-php-extensions-macos-homebrew/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reboot Your Mac

Hold Cmd + R

Open terminal

```
csrutil disable
reboot
```

run

```
sudo pecl install imagick
```

add

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-XXXXXX/imagick.so
```

to your php.ini after your instalation is done

reboot your mac
Hold Cmd + R

Open terminal

```
csrutil enable
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question:
[Homebrew: install new formula php72-imagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060021/homebrew-install-new-formula-php72-imagick/50529784#50529784)

You may need to change the path for your modules. (read STEP 4 and 5 in particular).