# failed to install php-extention with pecl on mac（ error tips：fail to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/msgpack）

Tags: php, macos, php-extension, pecl

No matter what php extention i install with `sudo pecl install xxx`, i was failed and got the following error tips:

[image]

Is there anyone who had the same problem ？

Comment: You are trying to write in `/usr/include/...` but **System Integrity Protection** does not allow that on a Mac https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899

Comment: Thanks a lot.So how to change the path to avoid this problem？Or maybe I should install PHP extensions compiled.

Comment: Personally, I use **homebrew** to install PHP https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529784/2836621

Answer (score -1):

You must run this as `root` if you want to install it in that location. If you cannot elevate your rights, then you need to install it elsewhere or ask your admin to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do run the command with the `root` user on my personal computer. But I failed. I even used the `chown` command to change the group to which I belonged.

Comment: Error message: ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/include/php/ext/msgpack

Comment: the error may indicate that either you do NOT run this as root, or that the `mkdir` is run without `-p` option so one/more of elements of target path does not exist and `mkdir` fails.