# Install phpredis MAC OSX

Tags: php, macos, redis, php-7.2

Can anyone help me install php-redis in MAC OSX .

```
brew install php-redis
```

not working.

```
pecl install php-redis
```

also not working getting -

> invalid package name/package file "php-redis".
>
> Homebrew Error:

[homebrew_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJgg7.png)

Comment: It'd be `pecl install redis`, and "not working" is pretty vague. Give us the errors/difficulties you encountered and maybe we can help with the Homebrew side.

Comment: Hi i have inserted homebrew install problem in image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJgg7.png 
I need to install php-redis . Already install redis with : brew install redis
which is working fine.

Comment: See here but adapt for Redis https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529784/2836621

Comment: `pecl help` is useful to discover `pecl search` which is useful , like : `pecl search edis` would have given you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @MarkSetchell point where you wrote " brew options this", there is no options for php-redis.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am saying. There is no `php-redis` any more, that's why you cannot do `brew install php-redis` nor `brew options php-redis`. You need to use `pecl` to install Redis and make it known to PHP.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
git clone https://www.github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git
cd phpredis
phpize && ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Add `extension=redis.so` in your php.ini

```
brew services restart php@7.2
make test
```

You can check working or not

```
php -r "if (new Redis() == true){ echo \"\r\n OK \r\n\"; }"
```

Comment: hi, this is a good guide to install phpredis, but where should i put phpredis directory ?

Comment: @Ivan : you can download in Download folder

Comment: if it doesn't work for you on OSX Mojave, this guy is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52530212/766570

Comment: It's work when I have put the complete path or redis.so in my php.ini

Comment: I have update php@8.0 again repeat above steps and working fine

Answer (score 53):

As of 2019, with homebrew php7.2 and up, `pecl` is now installed by default alongside the php binaries.

To see this for yourself type `which pecl`.

**Steps to install**

1. Check your version of redis, then find a suitable version of the extension [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis).
2. If unfamiliar with pecl, type `pecl` to see the options.
3. Issue `pecl install redis-5.0.2`. (or your version). Enter no to each question asked if you're not sure.
4. If that succeeds check the new file it created at: `/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/redis.so`
5. The install will have added `extension="redis.so"` to top of your php ini.
   Check that by opening the file `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini`.
   (assuming you're on 7.3 there)
6. `brew services restart php`.
7. `php -i | grep Redis`

```sh
Redis Support => enabled
Redis Version => 5.0.2
```

This is what I just did in September 2019 and it works for me.

Comment: Also after upgrading to PHP 7.4, I had to reinstall redis ext with pecl:
`pecl uninstall redis`, then `pecl install redis`

Comment: Worked for me as well for PHP 7.3. Thanks

Comment: If you get: Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294 error, run pecl config-get ext_dir | pbcopy, then mkdir -p {paste clipboard value}, then sudo pecl install redis-5.3.2

Comment: `pecl install redis` was not working for me without `sudo`: https://superuser.com/a/1707730/79629

Comment: If the extension isn't loading; in my case pecl installed `redis.so` in a different location. `pecl install redis-x` outputs this. After updating the top line in the php.ini file to the correct location the extension loaded correctly.

Comment: Just a note here that the install may not add the line `extension=redis.so` to php.ini, if its not in the default location, so you may need to aad it manually.
Here is what the install says after installing
`configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=redis.so" to php.ini`

Answer (score 12):

If what [mwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050854/2065804) wrote above doesn't work (please try their answer first),

first, try to uninstall first (if you have it but broken):

```
sudo pecl uninstall redis
```

and after that run:

```
sudo pecl install redis
```

After that, ini the php.ini, use full path for the extension.

Mine was /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.21/pecl/20180731/redis.so (assuming you are using php@7.3)

so at the top of my php.ini file is like this:

```
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.21/pecl/20180731/redis.so"
```

Answer (score 3):

If someone gets an error during `sudo pecl install redis`

> Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294
>
> PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/-----/pear/System.php on line 294

that means you need to create the broken directory manually.
Try to create the directory...

```
pecl config-get ext_dir | pbcopy
mkdir -p {paste clipboard value}
# in my case, it was
mkdir -p /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20200930
```

Now try to install any **pecl** extensions.

```
sudo pecl install redis
```

After installing any extension, restart **php**

```
brew services restart php
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: This is what I needed for installing on my machine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps to use `pickle`, for PHP >= 7.3 (tested with 8.1):

1. `brew install pickle`
2. `pickle install redis`
3. Find your php.ini location via `php -i|grep php.ini`
4. Edit the php.ini, insert `extension=redis`. Preferable at `Dynamic Extensions` section.
5. No restart of Apache httpd service is required. You may test your PHP code with Redis

**Bonus**

If you use VS Code, to enable intellisense / auto complete, at `Preference` -> paste `intelephense.stubs` at Search setting box -> Add Item -> select `redis`.

Answer (score 0):

If you got the following error,

> Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled

despite doing everything in the verified answer above, try `valet restart` . It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all these solutions but didn't work for me for a while so I tried this link https://developer.redis.com/develop/php/ from the original docs and it works as charm