# Laradock - PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled

Tags: laravel, docker, laradock, phpredis, laravel-horizon

i'm trying to enable Horizon on Laradock but i always received this message ***"Please make sure the PHP Redis extension is installed and enabled"***
I've accessed to Workspace container to check whether the php-redis extension is installed or not. But you can see the image the php-redis is already newest version
[docker-compose exec workspace bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXIm4.png)

I've open the .env of Laravel project and changed as below

```
REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

I've also open the .env file in Laradock folder and enable to all *`INSTALL_PHPREDIS=true`*. After that, **docker-compose build --no-cache workspace php-fpm php-worker**

This is [.env](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13-_f9fU8JkDstylr5-SM_1t-yITvJ44Q/view?usp=sharing) file of Laradock folder

But it's still error with php-redis extension

I found some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168156/logicexception-please-make-sure-the-php-redis-extension-is-installed-and-enable) that install predis . **but i dont want to use it**.
I would like to use **phpredis** and keep `'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis')` in config/database.php

Is there anybody faced this issued, please help me. Thank you so much

Comment: did you changed from this `'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),`
To:`'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),`,in `config/database.php` file

Comment: I don't want to use predis. So i would like to  phpredis so i did not install predis by composer require predis/predis

Comment: Did you enable the `redis` in `php.ini ` ?

Comment: why you are assigning `redis` to `REDIS_HOST` you have to assign it to `REDIS_CLIENT=predis`

Comment: I'm using laradock (https://laradock.io/) which is apply docker. And i really want to use phpredis. I don't like predis

Comment: post your full env file

Comment: I just edit my post

Comment: Check this video and make sure you follow the steps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEpyWEbsrkw

Comment: Thanks for your supporting, @Basharmal, But the video it's not what i'm looking for :(

Comment: Which platform are you using window or something else

Comment: Im using Mac, Docker Desktop and Laradock

Comment: Have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908004/install-phpredis-mac-osx

Comment: I'm using Docker, so it's may not help me

Answer (score 3):

I found the issued. Thanks to calebanthony from [GitHub](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/2875) .

> It looks like it's installing php8.0-redis instead of the version for
> 7.3 like I need. I manually edited my workspace/Dockerfile file manually on the PHPRedis section to install php7.3-redis instead of
> install php-redis. A hack, but got me live again.

I've been using php 7.3 so far. I hope this small thing can help someone. Thanks

Comment: Thanka. Just ran into this myself.